# iCloud fails to merge: Can't process log with score:

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm having some problems with CoreData and iCloud.

The app used to work fine, but some users have reported that the data is no longer syncing. 
After enabling debug loggin (setting the run-time parameter -com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.logLevel 3
) I managed to get an error message from the app:

```
2012-09-02 11:47:17.835 MyApp[29365:1a0f] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter canProcessTransactionLogWithScore:afterLogWithScore:](364): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter: 0xd692b60>:
    ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0xd6912e0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/ATCS9MGY4M~com~MyApp~MyApp/Data/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92
    localPeerID: mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170

Can't process log with score: {
    "mobile.A1F36BF9-B200-57C7-9A56-B6993451AA3D" = 4;
    "mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170" = "-58";
} after log with score: {
}
 It is ahead of the local peer.
2012-09-04 21:47:17.853 MyApp[29365:1a0f] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter createSortedOperationsArrayForLogLocations:](317): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter: 0xd692b60>:
    ubiquityRootLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0xd6912e0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/ATCS9MGY4M~com~MyApp~MyApp/Data/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92
    localPeerID: mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170

Giving up on operations:
(
    "<_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x2953c0>:\n\tlocalPeerIID: mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170\n\tlogScore: {\n    \"mobile.A1F36BF9-B200-57C7-9A56-B6993451AA3D\" = 4;\n    \"mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170\" = \"-58\";\n}\ntransactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x293f90>\n\ttransactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x2b3b20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/ATCS9MGY4M~com~MyApp~MyApp/Data/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92/mobile.A1F36BF9-B200-57C7-9A56-B6993451AA3D/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92/ZaJyBZ6MYNgth0Eai8Icgg2c1C~09IqT5LmGkD2D56I=/779B2C07-A286-4826-98D4-91BA461645E3.1.cdt\n\ttransactionNumber: 7\n\n",
    "<_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x292350>:\n\tlocalPeerIID: mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170\n\tlogScore: {\n    \"mobile.A1F36BF9-B200-57C7-9A56-B6993451AA3D\" = 5;\n    \"mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170\" = \"-58\";\n}\ntransactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x290f00>\n\ttransactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x2b11e0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/ATCS9MGY4M~com~MyApp~MyApp/Data/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92/mobile.A1F36BF9-B200-57C7-9A56-B6993451AA3D/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92/ZaJyBZ6MYNgth0Eai8Icgg2c1C~09IqT5LmGkD2D56I=/9AF49529-06D2-479D-B9D9-B43E18611172.1.cdt\n\ttransactionNumber: 8\n\n",
)
Due to incompatible operation: <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation: 0x2953c0>:
    localPeerIID: mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170
    logScore: {
    "mobile.A1F36BF9-B200-57C7-9A56-B6993451AA3D" = 4;
    "mobile.A9EC2335-92F9-5098-BF24-48D49DD7D170" = "-58";
}
transactionLog: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x293f90>
    transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x2b3b20>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/ATCS9MGY4M~com~MyApp~MyApp/Data/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92/mobile.A1F36BF9-B200-57C7-9A56-B6993451AA3D/4D90DDAD-FA00-49FF-9AEA-973ED3AE5A92/ZaJyBZ6MYNgth0Eai8Icgg2c1C~09IqT5LmGkD2D56I=/779B2C07-A286-4826-98D4-91BA461645E3.1.cdt
    transactionNumber: 7
```

anyone knows how to mitigate or what the root cause is for a these error messages;

- "It is ahead of the local peer."
- "Due to incompatbile operation: <_PFUbiquityRecordImportOperation:"

thanks

Comment: @andrew no, we have a huge work around in place :-(